# How can I convert the contents from 2 cells in a row (df) to say several more cells in the same row on Python? Pandas related

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, for-loop, cartesian-product

Let's say I have the following `df` (it's a little sample from a bigger one), each row contains 3 cells:

```
  Permutations                        FilePermutations
0 Fondo+Cuerpo+Ojos+Color+Pinzas+Puas Oceano.png+Cuerpo_cangrejo.png+Antenas.png+Amarillo.png+None+None
1 Fondo+Cuerpo+Ojos+Color+Pinzas+Puas Oceano.png+Cuerpo_cangrejo.png+Antenas.png+Amarillo.png+None+Arena.png
2 Fondo+Cuerpo+Ojos+Color+Pinzas+Puas Oceano.png+Cuerpo_cangrejo.png+Antenas.png+Amarillo.png+None+Marron.png
3 Fondo+Cuerpo+Ojos+Color+Pinzas+Puas Oceano.png+Cuerpo_cangrejo.png+Antenas.png+Amarillo.png+None+Purpura.png
4 Fondo+Cuerpo+Ojos+Color+Pinzas+Puas Oceano.png+Cuerpo_cangrejo.png+Antenas.png+Amarillo.png+None+Verde.png
.
.
.
```

All the cells from the column `Permutations` remain constant, this `df` represents some [Cartesian Products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) that were obtained as a result of a particular process.

How could I manage to make it look like this one below?

```
  Fondo            Cuerpo                     Ojos             Color              Pinzas      Puas   
0 Fondo Oceano.png Cuerpo Cuerpo_cangrejo.png Ojos Antenas.png Color Amarillo.png Pinzas None Puas None
1 Fondo Oceano.png Cuerpo Cuerpo_cangrejo.png Ojos Antenas.png Color Amarillo.png Pinzas None Puas Arena.png
2 Fondo Oceano.png Cuerpo Cuerpo_cangrejo.png Ojos Antenas.png Color Amarillo.png Pinzas None Puas Marron.png
3 Fondo Oceano.png Cuerpo Cuerpo_cangrejo.png Ojos Antenas.png Color Amarillo.png Pinzas None Puas Purpura.png
4 Fondo Oceano.png Cuerpo Cuerpo_cangrejo.png Ojos Antenas.png Color Amarillo.png Pinzas None Puas Verde.png
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the column names from the `Permutations` column by splitting it with `+` sign. Similarly, you can extract data from `FilePermutations` column.

```
import pandas as pd

old_df = pd.read_csv("cartesian.csv")
new_columns = old_df.iloc[0]['Permutations'].split("+")
new_data = []
for i in range(0, len(old_df)):
    row_data = old_df.iloc[i]['FilePermutations'].split("+")
    current_data = []
    for j, column in enumerate(new_columns):
        current_data.append(f"{column} {row_data[j]}")
    new_data.append(current_data)

updated_df = pd.DataFrame(data=new_data, columns=new_columns)
print(updated_df)
```

Output:

```
              Fondo                      Cuerpo  ...       Pinzas              Puas
0  Fondo Oceano.png  Cuerpo Cuerpo_cangrejo.png  ...  Pinzas None         Puas None
1  Fondo Oceano.png  Cuerpo Cuerpo_cangrejo.png  ...  Pinzas None    Puas Arena.png
2  Fondo Oceano.png  Cuerpo Cuerpo_cangrejo.png  ...  Pinzas None   Puas Marron.png
3  Fondo Oceano.png  Cuerpo Cuerpo_cangrejo.png  ...  Pinzas None  Puas Purpura.png
4  Fondo Oceano.png  Cuerpo Cuerpo_cangrejo.png  ...  Pinzas None    Puas Verde.png

[5 rows x 6 columns]
```

`cartesian.csv`

```
Permutations,FilePermutations
Fondo+Cuerpo+Ojos+Color+Pinzas+Puas,Oceano.png+Cuerpo_cangrejo.png+Antenas.png+Amarillo.png+None+None
Fondo+Cuerpo+Ojos+Color+Pinzas+Puas,Oceano.png+Cuerpo_cangrejo.png+Antenas.png+Amarillo.png+None+Arena.png
Fondo+Cuerpo+Ojos+Color+Pinzas+Puas,Oceano.png+Cuerpo_cangrejo.png+Antenas.png+Amarillo.png+None+Marron.png
Fondo+Cuerpo+Ojos+Color+Pinzas+Puas,Oceano.png+Cuerpo_cangrejo.png+Antenas.png+Amarillo.png+None+Purpura.png
Fondo+Cuerpo+Ojos+Color+Pinzas+Puas,Oceano.png+Cuerpo_cangrejo.png+Antenas.png+Amarillo.png+None+Verde.png
```